# ALT+TAB in Vista activates main window instead of previously active child window

Tags: c++, windows-vista, aero, childwindow

My app (written in C++) uses Win32 (not MFC) to create a couple of windows with CreateWindowEx. The main window gets the desktop as a parent, the child windows get the main window as a parent.

My problem:

- The app has an active child window
- I switch to another app (per click, ALT+TAB or other, doesn't matter)
- I switch back to my app with ALT+TAB

Now the main window of my app is activated, not the child window anymore. If I switch back clicking the taskbar entry, the child window remains active.

This happens only with Aero (with and without Glass). If I activate the classical Window Scheme, everything behaves as under Windows XP (switching back with ALT+TAB leaves the child window active).

Any suggestions or links or other resources?

(Sample code is a bit hard to provide since the UI-elements are wrapped in classes with own data types for strings etc.)

It seems that Vista with classical scheme sends an WM_ACTIVATE to the main window and another WM_ACTIVATE to the second window (owned by the main window).
With Vista Aero enabled only the main windows gets an WM_ACTIVATE. Odd.

Comment: Take a look at the WMs coming through. Perhaps you can recognize the difference in Aero?

Comment: Do you know a simple way to translate the message-id into text like "WM_ACTIVATE"? It would make things easier...